# "Argument x" in length function

Tags: r

Am working through the section on vectors in "The Book on R", which has given the following examples:

```
length(x=c(3,2,8,1)) 
# [1] 4

length(x=5:13) 
# [1] 9

foo <- 4 

bar <- c(3,8.3,rep(x=32,times=foo),seq(from=-2,to=1,length.out=foo+1)) 

length(x=bar) 
# [1] 11
```

But if the input `length(c(3,2,8,1))` is going to give you the output `4` anyway, why would you add in `x=`? What is the purpose of `x=`? At first I thought it had to do with variables but R did not reflect that x was holding the vector (3,2,8,1) after I typed `length(x=c(3,2,8,1))`.

And why does `length(y=c(5:13))` does not work but gives an error:

> Error in length(y = 5:13) : supplied argument name 'y' does not match 'x'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R has named arguments for functions. Check [this section of R's doc for some information on the subject](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Named-arguments-and-defaults).

So `x` is just the name that was given to the first argument of function `length`, it has nothing to do with any variable in your environment that may be named `x`.

Overall, it's a pretty handy feature:

- it allows you to pass arguments in any order (if you use the `arg = ...` syntax)
- the function's writer can give hints to users about what type of arguments are expected
- combined with auto-completion, it helps to remember a function's syntax and usage
- and it is optional, since you can also pass arguments without naming them:

'

```
matrix(data = 1:12, ncol = 3)  # is equivalent to:
matrix(1:12,,3)
```

You can also use it to write some really confusing stuff (*of course, not recommended*), such as:

```
x <- 1:3
length(x = x)  # 3
length(x = (x <- 1:4))  # 4 ...
x  # 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: In comment please. Or illustrate your answer. Thank you.